# Flash content loaded in IFRAME get disappeared while applying transform:scale css property in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe, transform

I have an iframe loaded with an html file with flash content inside, and i have to resize the iframe while browser window width changes. So i tried changing transform:scale() property on different media query cut-offs. But unfortunately firefox makes the flash content disappear while applying transform-scale property. Is there any way to overcome this?

**HTML**

```
<iframe width="900px" class="iframeStyle" align="middle" height="1200px" frameborder="0" src="http://linktoFlashContainingHtml.html"> </iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
.iframeStyle {
    transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your flash is running in windowless mode if you want it to play nice with CSS effects.  See http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_.